# Stop Google Calendar Event notification for Specific case

Tags: php, laravel, google-calendar-api, google-client

I have created a Calendar App where users can add their events and user can sync this Calendar with their Google Calendar. Basically, it is a two-way syncing.

Here is how it's working:

1. When a user adds a new event in the calendar app, it is adding to Google Calendar.
2. When User Adding an event in Google Calendar directly it is syncing to my Calendar App via Calendar Notifications (Channel notification).

Problem is that when user adding an event in my calendar App it's adding to Google Calendar and I am getting sync notification and system adding/updating the recently added event again.

So, I am searching a way that I should not get sync notification when an event just added from my Calendar App.

Comment: @DalmTo I don't get any way turning off notifications for a specific case. And turning off notification will not be a solution to the problem because we need notifications for Case2 to sync Google event in my app calendar.

Comment: your question is unclear please edit your question and include enough code to show the problem and describe the issues you are having with your solution